# Clustering temporal data

Tags: clustering, data-visualization, dataset

I have a large collection of bus arrival times (a specific bus number at a specific stop). I am trying to determine the best way to cluster the data so I can see what time the bus usually shows up at - I know how many clusters there should be as I know e.g. every day this bus shows up at this stop 10 times, so 10 clusters.

The data is as follows: 7.43, 7.40, 7.45, 12.00, 12. 04, 11.59, 1.00, 1.01, 1.01 for three days. So I know there should be three clusters - but I am not sure the best way to implement this. Im also struggling with how to visualise this - since its just what times of the day did the bus show up.

Comment: Convert the times to continuous values (e.g. minutes after midnight). Then run any clustering algorithm you like. They should all yield similar results because the stop times are fairly regular, and widely separated. To visualize, estimate the distribution of times for each cluster (e.g. histogram, KDE, or simple Gaussian distribution if there's little data). If you use a Gaussian mixture model for clustering, you'll get this automatically. Then, plot the distributions, colored separately for each cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can for instance define the distance between two points to be the difference in time (say number of minutes). Then you can apply hierarchical clustering. A dendrogram is a good visualization, it will also make the choice of the number of clusters obvious.

If you have a very large dataset, you might apply k-means instead (you have to set the number of clusters) or you can even combine the two: first apply k-means with a large number of clusters, and then apply hierarchical clustering on the cluster means. To represent the data for k-means, you can use the number of minutes from the beginning of the day. To combine the two, I suggest to use the euclidean distance and Ward criterion for hierarchical clustering so the two clustering optimize the same criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Choose those times with the highest number of matches with +- 10 minutes. Then remove them from the data set. Cost the next densest now. Repeat.

It's better to use domain knowledge (e.g. schedules aren't 10 minutes, delays of 5 minutes are common) rather than hoping a method designed for a completely different purpose works.

Above approach will ignore a bus that ran complete our of schedule, whereas KMeans would still try to cluster that outlier!